# Grouping duplicates by boolean column not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table customer, that has following columns:

```
create table customer
(
    id                                 bigserial.              primary key,
    external_id                        text                                      not null,
    name                               text,
    default_sender_address             bigint
        constraint customer_default_sender_address_fkey
            references address_book,
    information                        text,
    updated_by                         text,
    created_by                         text,
    created_at                         timestamp with time zone default now(),
    updated_at                         timestamp with time zone default now(),
    external_subcustomer               text                     default ''::text not null,
    type                               text,
    credit_blocked                     boolean                  default false    not null,
    mandatory_subcustomer              boolean                  default false    not null,
    external_uuid                       uuid
        constraint customer_external_uuid_key
            unique,
    external_parent_uuid                uuid,
    is_deleted                         boolean                  default false    not null,
);
```

I have a query where I would like to fetch all duplicates that have `false` value for `is_deleted` column:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM customer a
         JOIN (SELECT external_id, external_subcustomer, COUNT(*)
               FROM customer
               GROUP BY external_id, external_subcustomer, is_deleted = false
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b
              ON a.external_id = b.alystra_id
                  AND a.external_subcustomer = b.external_subcustomer
WHERE (a.external_subcustomer = '' or a.external_subcustomer is null) AND is_deleted = false
ORDER BY a.external_subcustomer;
```

When I execute this query I get all the duplicates, but also the ones that have `is_deleted` set to `true`.
Why are those not filtered out and only the ones with `false` grouped together as duplicates?
What am I doing wrong with this query?

Comment: You have not qualified all your columnns with an alias; and is `is_deleted = false` even valid in your group by, should that not be a `where` criteria or correlated?

Comment: How should that be done? @Stu

Answer (score 0):

The criteria for is_deleted belongs to the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT cust.*
FROM customer cust
JOIN (
    SELECT external_id, external_subcustomer
    FROM customer
    WHERE is_deleted = false
    GROUP BY external_id, external_subcustomer
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) dups 
   ON cust.external_id = dups.external_id
  AND cust.external_subcustomer = dups.external_subcustomer 
WHERE TRIM(cust.external_subcustomer) = ''
  AND cust.is_deleted = false
ORDER BY cust.external_subcustomer;
```